# How do I accept these params in a ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so i want to declare a method that will accept params like this

Lets say my method is named custom_method

```
@variable.custom_method(Profile, :as => @user)
```

My method should catch the variable @user and call the `@user.profile`

but how do i catch the second param which is a hash

Comment: Declare a parameter in the method signature?

Answer (score 2):

The simpler solution is probably:

```
def custom_method(association, args)
  obj = args[:as] or fail("Missing argument :as => obj")
  obj.send(association.name.underscore)
  ...
end
```

Richer calls to functions, but the downside is clear: the method signature loses information.

Comment: You can use the .send(method_name) method. Use it like this: @user.send("profile") or @user.send(:profile)